# Addressing individual cells in a non-enumerable datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, ienumerable, datarow, datacolumn

I have a datatable that may contain null or empty cells, due to dirty data. Cleaning the data is not an option in this scenario.

Because I need a singular string output per row (the number of rows may change, the number of columns is a constant (3)), I need to address each individual cell, in order to tell the method what to do if a cell happens to be empty. I originally tried the following:

dataset: con.dSet
list<>: Officers

```
bool notNull(var cell)
{
    if (cell != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void hereAreAllThePeople()
{
    if (con.dSet != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            foreach (DataColumn col in row)
            {
                if (notNull)
                {
                    str += col.ToString();
                }
                else if (!notNull)
                {
                    str += "";
                }
            }
            Officers.Add(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Its ugly, and it falls over because `row` is not enumerable. How do I get by this?

Comment: Use a classic for loop instead of foreach? You should also avoid ambiguous names like dSet and con if wherever possible to make the code readable to others.

Comment: @user3427079 True, I tried to to that here. dSet for DataSet, and con for Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is pretty manky code but I suppose you could do this:

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dSet.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                if (notNull)
                {
                    str += row[col].ToString();
                }
                else if (!notNull)
                {
                    str += "";
                }
            }
```

of, knowing you have three fields,

```
for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
{
if (notNull)
                    {
                        str += row[i].ToString();
                    }
                    else if (!notNull)
                    {
                        str += "";
                    }

}
```

Edited (because I cant comment for some reason)
OK, I'm not sure what you want out of this, but I'm not seeing the notNull varaible being set anywhere so am not sure how you are using it. Based on the stated goal of your question, this will work as you expect:

```
void hereAreAllThePeople()
{
    if (con.dSet != null)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
            Officers.Add(string.Join("", row.ItemArray.Select(p => (p == null) ? "": p.ToString()).ToArray()));
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only issue I have here is that this will also fall over of one of the columns(or rather, cells) is null. By fall over, I mean that the method will skip the entire row, and not just that cell.

Comment: Yup, that'll require another loop where you check per cell for every row whether it's empty or not and put in an EMPTY code of some sort if it is.